# How to implement a SLICE function in an Android Game?

Tags: android

I am creating a simple game for thesis. It doesn't have Activity classes but instead has Screen classes for each level. I would like to implement a SLICE functionality for this game. For example, the user would slice at the enemy to attack it.

I tried searching Google for this, but nothing comes up but the Slice game, slice() function in javascript, etc. I really don't know what to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you really want is a "swipe" gesture, which recognizes someone quickly moving their finger across the screen.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/793607) describes a great way of implementing such a gesture, and you could possibly modify it to parameters that "feel" right for your slice.